How to convert these equations from LaTeX to Word with pandoc?
I have a document that I wrote years ago in LaTeX, and now I need it in Word format. The text part works fine using pandoc, but this document contains a large number of math equations. I used some uncommon packages in LaTeX for these equations, and pandoc cannot render them in Word.
Here are the header of my original LaTeX file and some equations that cannot be rendered by pandoc:
%% headers
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,hyperref}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

%% some example equations that cannot be converted to Word

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{\abs{\mathbf{q}} = f}\binom{f}{\mathbf{q}} q_{m}
    \prod_{i} {\varphi_{i}}^{q_{i}} =
    \varphi_{m} f \abs{\bm{\varphi}}^{f-1} .
\end{equation}

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{\substack{\lvert \mathbf{u} \rvert = m \\ \lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert = n}}
    \binom{m}{\mathbf{u}} \binom{n}{\mathbf{v}} 
    \underbrace{(k_1 u_p + k_2 v_q)}_{\text{linear combination}}
    \prod_{i} a_i^{u_i} \prod_{j} b_j^{v_j} 
    &= k_1 a_p m \abs{\mathbf{a}}^{m-1}  \abs{\mathbf{b}}^{n}
    + k_2 \abs{\mathbf{a}}^{m} b_q n \abs{\mathbf{b}}^{n-1} \\
    &= \left[\frac{k_1 m a_p}{\abs{\mathbf{a}}} + \frac{k_2 n b_q}{\abs{\mathbf{b}}} \right]
    \abs{\mathbf{a}}^{m} \abs{\mathbf{b}}^{n} ,
\end{align*}


The error message from pandoc says many times
  unexpected control sequence \abs
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\tag", "\\nonumber", whitespace or "\\allowbreak"

and also some
  unexpected "\\"
  expecting "&", "\\\\", white space or "\\end"

Is there any way for me to resolve these so I can convert these equations to Word with pandoc?

Welcome. // Can you please add to your question, how you use pandoc in this case, e.g. on the Latex code you posted? // If everything fails, would creating images from your (critical) equations help resolving the issue?

@MS-SPO I could reproduce by adding \documentclass{article}, \begin{document} after the paired delimiter declarations, and \end{document} at the end, and converting with pandoc myfile.tex -o myfileconverted.docx.

@MS-SPO I used pandoc mydoc.tex -o mydoc.docx. If everything can be consistently converted into images that's fine, but I haven't figured out how to do that either.

@Marijn Thank you!
